# Centering Nodes Vertically

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am learning tikz.

I would like to centre two vertically on the right of three nodes.

In the attached code I can position to the right of the nodes, but not vertically centre the nodes.

Could some point out how to achieve this using tikz?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle,draw}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.10cm and 2.0cm]

\node[block] (node1) { Column 1 Row 1 };
\node[block, below=of node1] (node2) { Column 1 Row 2 };
\node[block, below=of node2] (node3) { Column 1 Row 3 };
\node[block, below=of node3] (node4) { Column 1 Row 4 };
\node[block, right=of node2] (node5) { Column 2 vertically centered between Nodes 2-4 };
\node[block, below=of node5] (node6) { Column 2 vertically centered between Nodes 2-4 };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that you are positioning the top of one node relative to the center of another.  As opposed to `\node[bellow] at (node1.south) ...`

Answer (score 1):

I am also learning Ti*k*Z. You need to load the library `positioning` in order to make your code go through. Do you want something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle,draw}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.10cm and 2.0cm]

\node[block] (node1) { Column 1 Row 1 };
\node[block, below=of node1] (node2) { Column 1 Row 2 };
\node[block, below=of node2] (node3) { Column 1 Row 3 };
\node[block, below=of node3] (node4) { Column 1 Row 4 };
\coordinate[right=of node1] (right);
\coordinate (vert) at ($(node2.center)!0.5!(node3.center)$);
\node[block,anchor=west] (node5) at (vert-|right) { Column 2 vertically centered between Nodes 2-4 };
\node[block, below=of node5] (node6) { Column 2 vertically centered between Nodes 2-4 };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

with help of the packages `positioning` and `chains`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains, positioning}

\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw, on chain}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=1mm and 20mm,
start chain=going below
                        ]
\node[block] (node1) { Column 1 Row 1 };
\node[block] (node2) { Column 1 Row 2 };
\node[block] (node3) { Column 1 Row 3 };
\node[block] (node4) { Column 1 Row 4 };
    \begin{scope}[node distance=0.5mm and 20mm]
\node[block, above right=of $(node2.south)!0.5!(node4.north)$] (node5)
            { Column 2 vertically centered between Nodes 2-4 };
\node[block, below right=of $(node2.south)!0.5!(node4.north)$] (node6)
            { Column 2 vertically centered between Nodes 2-4};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=1mm and 20mm,
start chain=going below,
block/.append style={text width=32mm, align=left}
                        ]
\node[block] (node1) { Column 1 Row 1 };
\node[block] (node2) { Column 1 Row 2 };
\node[block] (node3) { Column 1 Row 3 };
\node[block] (node4) { Column 1 Row 4 };
    \begin{scope}[node distance=0.5mm and 20mm]
\node[block, above right=of $(node2.south)!0.5!(node4.north)$] (node5)
            { Column 2 vertically centered between Nodes 2-4 };
\node[block, below right=of $(node2.south)!0.5!(node4.north)$] (node6)
            { Column 2 vertically centered between Nodes 2-4};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

however, when nodes in second column haven't the same height, their vertical centering is not trivial anymore.